# Unit test fails because the service is offline

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a unit test that fails because it indirectly calls a method which is dependent upon a service. But when unit tests are run, the service is offline. I tried using Mockito for mocking the behavior of this service dependent method, but the problem is that this method is a static method in a final class, so Mockito does not work in this case.

I also tried using PowerMock with Mockito, but again as the method is not called directly from the unit test, it does not work. This is the skeleton of my unit test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FinalClassWithStaticMethod.class)
public class MyObjTestCase {
    @Test public void myRandomTest() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FinalClassWithStaticMethod.class);
        MyObj returnObj = new MyObj();
        // setup fields for returnObj
        ...
        ...
        PowerMockito.when(FinalClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod((AnotherObj)anyObject())).thenReturn(returnObj);
        AnotherObj obj = new AnotherObj();
        // setup fields for obj...

        MyObj mockedObj =     FinalClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod(obj); // This returns the mocked value.
        // TestUtil.staticMethod calls another class' method which calls FinalClassWithStaticMethod.staticMethod.
        MyObj myObj = TestUtil.staticMethod(obj); // This does not return mocked value.
    }
}
```

My questions:

Are the unit tests even meant for such scenarios?

Is there a way by which I can get this unit test to work without modifying the final class? In case I do have to modify the existing classes, what is the correct way of doing it by minimal effects on the dependent code? Although it is a specific scenario, links to examples that exhibit such refactoring will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should ideally be mocking the service object. The mocking will only work if the method that is calling the service is using the mocked object. If the client for the service can be created and passed to the class calling the service directly from the unit test (setter/constructor) when the object is created in the unit test, then you don't have to make too many changes.

Sample code:

```
class CallsService {
    public CallsService(final ServiceClient client) {
    ... }
    public someMethod() {
        client.callService();
    }
}
```

In unit test:

```
void test() {
    ServiceClient mockedClient = mock(ServiceClient.class);
    // Setup mocks to return as required
    CallsService caller = new CallsService(mockedClient);
}
```

This way the caller will use the mockedClient in the unit test, and in the actual program it can get a client to the real service.